# replace word with content of another file with absolute paths on a remote machine?

Tags: linux, sed, replace, ansible

I have a kickstart file on a remote machine to which I would like to add the ssh key of the user of the remote machine without having that pub file locally.
My plan is to add a shell section to the ansible playbook to perform this task.
So far my testing was havin 2 files and replacing the required section using sed. I have the following:

file1:

```
aaa
bbb
text "REPLACE"
ccc
```

file2:

```
1233456
```

using `sed -i "s@REPLACE@$(cat file2)@g" file1` it replaces the text.

However when I add the absolute path `sed -i "s@REPLACE@$(cat /home/me/test/file2)@g" /home/me/test/file1` the command fails.

What could solve this problem?

edit: to clarify the ansible is provisioning the remote machine for various tasks amongst which is PXE boot server. the solution using ansible replace works very nice in this case.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether those files are indeed in those specified directories on the remote machine or not; it's also not clear how (on which machine) you did your testing w/o the absolute paths. Can you please clarify by editing your question accordingly?

Comment: `I would like to add the ssh key of the user of the remote machine without having that pub file locally` means there is a file contains a public key on remote host and you want to append it to the `authorized_keys` file? why is the replace?

Comment: Do you already wrote any Ansible task for that? Or what is the relation to Ansible, that you mentioned the [Ansible tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the files

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/file1
aaa
bbb
text "REPLACE"
ccc
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/file2
1233456
```

Use the module [*replace*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#ansible-builtin-replace-module-replace-all-instances-of-a-particular-string-in-a-file-using-a-back-referenced-regular-expression) to update the file. For example, the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - name: Read file2
      command: cat /tmp/file2
      register: file2

    - name: Update file1
      replace:
        path: /tmp/file1
        regexp: '^(.*)REPLACE(.*)$'
        replace: '\g<1>{{ file2.stdout }}\g<2>'
```

updates the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/file1
aaa
bbb
text "1233456"
ccc
```

---

Running the playbook with --diff mode gives

```bash
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -D

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [Read file2] ****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Update file1] **************************************************************************
--- before: /tmp/file1
+++ after: /tmp/file1
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 aaa
 bbb
-text "REPLACE"
+text "1233456"
 ccc

changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```